# If someone forgot to recite the Havdalah section in Yom Tov Kiddush, must he repeat any part of kiddush?

Tags: halacha, mistakes, yom-tov, havdalah, kiddush

When Yom Tov falls on Saturday night, Havdalah is included in Kiddush. If someone forgot to say the two blessings *M'oraui Ha'esh* and *Hamavdil* does he need to repeat any part of Kiddush? If so, which parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Aruch Hashulchan 473:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9102&st=&pgnum=101) says that is one forgot to make Havdala and remembered once he began the Hagada, he should wait until the Second cup and make Havdala on the second cup. If he remembered in middle of Shulchan Aruch, if he had in mind to drink during the Seuda, he should make Havdala without saying Borei Pri Hagefen, if he did not intend to drink wine during the Seuda he should just say Borei Pri Hagefen and Havdala and drink the wine.

This would indicate to me that on a regular Yom Tov, one would not repeat any part of Kiddush just say the Bracha of Havdala if he is still in middle of his meal so long he intended to drink wine at the meal.